# Programmatic Change in Select(ListBox) with .filter() works in Chrome but not IE11

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have a function called by a selectionChange event that replicates the selection in a visible select box to a hidden but otherwise identical select box.  The code I use to do this works in Chrome, but fails in IE11 (removes all selections in the hidden select box).

```
self.selectionChanged = function () {
                $('select#ListHidden option').removeAttr("selected");
                $('#ListVisible option:selected').each(function (n, item) {
                    $('#ListHidden option').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).text()) === item.text; }).attr('selected', true);
                });
            };
```

I was able to fix the error by replacing the .filter() method with bulkier code below.

```
self.selectionChanged = function () {
                $('select#ListHidden option').prop("selected", false);
                $('#ListVisible option:selected').each(function (n, item) {
                    var a = $.trim($(this).text());
                    $('#ListHidden > option').each(function() {
                        var c = $.trim($(this).text());
                        if (a === c) {
                            $(this).prop('selected', true);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
```

It works with the altered approach, but I'm just curious why my first attempt did not work.  Was I implementing this approach incorrectly?  If so then why did it work in Chrome?  Is there a cleaner way of doing this that will increase compatibility?

Comment: This doesn't look like Knockout.

Comment: the only part that is done in knockout is the initial function call and binding to the visible select box. 'self.selectionChanged = function () {'

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner and more cross-platform compatible if you used Knockout throughout or didn't use Knockout at all. Knockout is designed to handle all manipulations of the DOM through the viewmodel. Combining it with jQuery DOM manipulations is likely to lead to fighting.

It looks like the work you're doing here is exactly the sort of thing that would be automatically handled if the select had the proper bindings. There is no such thing as a "selectChange" binding in Knockout. There should be an `options` binding and a `value` binding. If there is an `event: { change: selectionChanged }` binding, just take it out and handle the event with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you.  My terminology in the original question is definitely not correct I'll edit and rephrase.  The select from my view look like the following; <select id="ListVisible" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" data-bind="options: availableTypes, selectedOptions: selectedTypes, event: { change: selectionChanged }, select2: { placeholder: 'Please Select One' }"></select>